# How do you create a powerpoint add-in that AUTOMATICALLY adds itself to the ribbon as soon as you import it?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote a PowerPoint macro, and I already know how to add it to the PowerPoint ribbon:
    Step 1: Import the macro in File->Options->Add-ins.
    Step 2: Customize the ribbon in File->Options->Customize Ribbon.

However, I'm trying to distribute this macro to all of my co-workers (not all of whom are tech-savvy), so it would be super convenient if Step 2 was not necessary.

I know it's SOMEHOW possible, but is there an EASY way?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Forgot to mention: I currently have the macro saved as a .ppam file.

Comment: Would you consider adding custom ribbon to `.ppam` an "easy way"?

Comment: Are you talking about this? http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01216-Create-an-ADD-IN-with-Ribbon-buttons-that-run-macros-when-clicked.htm

Comment: You're on the right track. Ribbon customization through the UI only gets you per-installation changes that don't travel with the file. If you use RibbonUI (or Fluent UI) custom XML, the customization will move with the file. For functions that are used occasionally, it can be enough to distribute a .pptm file that the user opens when they need the function. But for commands that should always be available, an add-in is the way to go. Here's a modern utility to help you edit Ribbon UI XML: https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor

Comment: More useful links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/custom_UI.html https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html

Comment: @BorisChernis Yes. You can create a custom ribbon for the file. I make mine by hand, but you can use software as suggested in one of the other comments.